# Another question on servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jasper-reports, tomcat5.5

As I have asked  [the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953956/javax-servlet-servletexception-wrapper-cannot-find-servlet-class) about servlet ,which is for showing a report on browser. I reconstruct a Danymic web project(named JasperServlet) using Eclipse,after creating . compiling and maping servlet(named `FirstReportSendToBrowserServlet`) ,  put the servlet into `Apache Tomcat v5.5` ,after I fire up tomcat, open http://localhost:8080/JasperServlet/FR (FirstReportSendToBrowserServlet has mapped to FR in  web.xml) , what I got puzzled me:

> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: **Error instantiating servlet class**
>   FirstReportSendToBrowserServlet
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) root cause
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRException
>     java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
>     java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
>     java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
>     java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
>     java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

I have already find in [Apache's bugzilla](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/) , But it seems that I can not find a similar answer. Do somebody can give hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `jasper-reports.jar` in your `WEB-INF/lib`. NoClassDefFoundError means the application expects a class to be on the classpath, but it is missing. The classpath of a web application is formed by:

- WEB-INF/classes
- WEB-INF/lib
- the container libraries